# How to split a TeraDataSQL column after a number of values

Tags: teradata

I am trying to split a SQL column from weeks to months. The column reads the year, then the week number from that year.

For example:

```
week_ID
201742
```

Which means, 2017, and the 42nd week of that year.

I am trying to get the column to split after the year so that the year will be in one column and the week number in a separate.

For example:

```
Year Week  
2017  42
```

I will then be using the week column to set the week number equal to a month.

Comment: Why can't you just use substring?

Comment: When I try to do that, I get a Parse Error splitting statement error.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `week_ID` is defined as `INTEGER`:

```
week_ID / 100 as yr, week_ID MOD 100 as wk
```

`DECIMAL(6,0)`:

```
cast(week_ID as int) / 100 as yr, week_ID MOD 100 as wk
```

`CHAR(6)`:

```
substring(week_ID from 1 for 4) as yr, substring(week_ID from 5) as wk
```

Comment: when i use substring I get a parse error splitting statement error

Comment: @Haley: What's the datatye of `week_ID`?

Comment: the type is integer

Comment: @Haley: Why do you apply SUBSTRING when the datatype is INT?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. I am familiar with some basic SQL but I have never had to break up a column before.

Comment: @Haley: SUBSTRING is a string function, but your column is an INTEGER. My answer covers three different datatypes, pick the correct one.